# How to reuse a grid in XAML in UWP Windows 10

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I currently have a Pivot with 3 grids and a ScrollViewer with the same grids. As any software engineer would do, I would like to just have the code once, instead of twice. So my question is: How do I do this?

Comment: An example would be appreciated as I cannot find a proper one.

Comment: Please find the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Comment: Those are WPF examples, I'm looking for UWP examples (Windows 10) as mentioned in the title.

Comment: XAML is 90% same across platforms, so feel free to use WPF examples :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about “reuse”, do you want to reuse the properties setting or something else? There are several ways for reusing, you need to choose the proper one depending on which parts you want to reuse.

Comment: @JeffreyChen-MSFT I have 3 grids I'm using twice, which I'd like to use once. But I already figured it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution: I put my three grids in three seperate DataTemplates and reference to those templates from within the Pivot and from within the ScrollViewer:

```
<Page.Resources>
   ...
   <DataTemplate x:Key="JustANormalGridNr1">
      <Grid />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="JustANormalGridNr2">
      <Grid />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="JustANormalGridNr3">
      <Grid />
   </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MasterGrid">
   <Pivot>
      <Pivot.Items>
         <PivotItem>
            ...
            <Grid>
               <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr1}" /><!--instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
         </PivotItem>
         <PivotItem>
            ...
            <Grid>
               <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr2}" /><!--instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
         </PivotItem>
         <PivotItem>
            ...
            <Grid>
               <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr3}" /><!--instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
         </PivotItem>
      </Pivot.Items>
   </Pivot>

   <ScrollViewer>
      <Grid>
         <Grid>
            ...
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
               ...
               <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr1}" /><!-- Instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
               ...
               <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr2}" /><!-- Instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
               ...
               <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JustANormalGridNr3}" /><!-- Instead of the grid, a reference to it -->
            </Grid>
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```